# Microsoft flow return JSON wrong format

Tags: power-automate

Currently I have this:
[image]

Which is the output I want so just 1 as output

But the next step is parse JSON which results in this output:
[image]

How can I make that the parse JSON also returns 1 as output without the rest of the text?

Answer (score 0):

In the step after "Parse JSON", you'll be able to select "id" in your "Dynamic content" and that will be just "1"